# issue with prerendering as web app is deployed on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I just deployed a react app on netlify and  I have turned on the prerender feature of the web app .However, what i see is that after deploying when I check 
curl -A googlebot xyz.com ,I don't see any output rendered on my terminal .Without making any changes, I wrote the same command  and after few hours I could see the pre rendering happening .
Is this correct or say normal ?Has others too faced the same issue and what do you receommend to check instantly that things are working .

Answer (score 0):

I used a prerender and this worked as you told. The content started to appear gradually.